# How to increase the size of a current focused item on a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv

I'm trying to make an horizontal list with a `RecyclerView`, that when I put the focus on an item, increase the size of this. I want to make this effect:

[image: Increased item effect]

Do you have any ideas to accomplish this?

Comment: I do exactly the same. but has no effect on my `RecyclerList`. I have an image view on my view holder and I want to be bigger when focus. Help me!

Comment: Hi @SadeqShajary, maybe you should apply the focusChangeListener to the root view instead of the imageView itself. This was developed and tested on Android TV, using a remote control.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question - you should post it as an answer to be consistent with Stack Overflow's Q&A format.

Comment: can this be done in App onTouch of Recyclerview Item

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Thanks to [dextor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1367571/dextor) answer, I could figure out this answer.

I've used the `FocusChangeListener` and added animation states to change the size of the view:

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public ViewHolder(final View root) {
    // bind views
    // ...

    // bind focus listener
    root.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
         @Override
         public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
             if (hasFocus) {
                 // run scale animation and make it bigger
                 Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale_in_tv);
                 root.startAnimation(anim);
                 anim.setFillAfter(true);
             } else {
                 // run scale animation and make it smaller
                 Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.scale_out_tv);
                 root.startAnimation(anim);
                 anim.setFillAfter(true);
             }
         }
    });
}
```

And the code for the anims:

scale_in_tv:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="100%"
    android:fromYScale="100%"
    android:toXScale="110%"
    android:toYScale="110%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%">
</scale>
```

scale_out_tv:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromXScale="110%"
    android:fromYScale="110%"
    android:toXScale="100%"
    android:toYScale="100%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%">
</scale>
```

Comment: How does this differ from my solution, and why was the accepted answer (mine) removed after almost one year?

Answer (score 25):

I'm imagining something like this:

1. Create the horizontal RV
2. When binding the ViewHolder, attach a `FocusChangeListener` to the root view of the item
3. When the item gains focus, scale it to make it slightly bigger; when the focus is lost, revert the animation.

---

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

  public ViewHolder(View root) {
    // bind views
    // ...

    // bind focus listener
    root.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
      @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
          if (hasFocus) {
            // run scale animation and make it bigger
          } else {
            // run scale animation and make it smaller
          }
        }
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: This Solution only works for Android TV, but not for the Mobile Devices... :-(

Comment: @Pawan : have you tried by giving  android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" to your root view in xml

Comment: I had to include `android:clickable="true"` AND `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` in order for it to work