# How to apply ItemDecoration from left and right side both to RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, item-decoration

I have been trying to achieve this for so long. What I want is to overlap the selected `RecyclerView` item from left and right as shown in the picture below.

[image]
[image]

I'm able to achieve left or right by `ItemDecoration` like below:

```
class OverlapDecoration(private val overlapWidth:Int) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    private val overLapValue = -40

    val TAG = OverlapDecoration::class.java.simpleName

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect, view: View, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State?) {

        val itemPosition = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)

        if (itemPosition == 0) {
            return
        } else {
            outRect.set(overLapValue, 0, 0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

I have achieved like below image so far.
[image]

I have already tried with [CarouselLayoutManager](https://github.com/Azoft/CarouselLayoutManager) but it not what I'm looking for.

Comment: setting itemDecoration(assigning overlap value to left and riht end at a time) to selctedItem and null to another will not help?

Comment: @VirRajpurohit Already tried, not working!

Comment: @Maddy Have you tried doing so with animations? Here is similar question
https://stackoverflow.com/q/33269409/548208

Comment: @DhruvMevada Yes, It also gives the same result as ItemDecoration with the negative margin.

Comment: Maybe this library can help you, although I've never used it myself - https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView

Comment: @Tohu tried already

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the result you're looking for you need to take two steps:

**First, to correct the decorator calculations:**

```
if (itemPosition == 0) {
    return
} else {
    outRect.set(-1 * overLapValue, 0, overLapValue, 0) //Need left, AND right
}
```

**Second, you need to actually add the shadow**

And, one quick bit of cleanup for the class, you don't need the `private val overLapValue`.

*Instead:*

```
class OverlapDecoration(private val overlapWidth:Int = 40) : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want! It will only increase the space from the right item. Actually, I want the right item to go under the selected item in RecyclerView.